# Creating Dynamic Pie Charts using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts

Gthompson83 gave me a great suggestion in using jqPlot, but here is my issue now...

I have the following javascript code on my page (the current data is just filler):

```
function CreatePie(div) {        
        var data = [
          ['Heavy Industry', 12], ['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14],
          ['Out of home', 16], ['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
        ];
        var plot2 = jQuery.jqplot(div, [data],
          {
              seriesDefaults: {
                  renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                  rendererOptions: {
                      // Turn off filling of slices.
                      fill: false,
                      showDataLabels: true,
                      // Add a margin to seperate the slices.
                      sliceMargin: 4,
                      // stroke the slices with a little thicker line.
                      lineWidth: 5
                  }
              },
              legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
          }
        );
    }
```

I call the function from the asp.net code-behind page as a startup script, like so.:

```
string script = string.Format("CreatePie('{0}')", "chartDiv" + k,);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "pieChart"+k,
                                   "<script>" + script + "</script>");
```

The one argument passed is the div into which the chart will be placed. Now how do I pass the data variables so they can be placed in the `data = [ [var1, value1], [var2, value2]...]` portion of the Javascript code?

Comment: We will be happy to help you, but first you will need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried. For example, the code that you've used, what the expected results were, and what you actually got instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jqPlot.  It's javascript based solution. Use asp.net to output the data for the javascript variable.

Comment: I tried the jqPlot and it's pretty awesome. How do I pass the data values from asp.net?